# I need to deserialize a JSON array to a HashMap with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json file which I need to deserialize into a HashMap.

I need a HashMap of type {name, HashMap<valuename, value>}

Example: {aaa={value1=111, value2=222, value3=333}, bbb={value1=444, value2=555, value3=666}}

Unfortunately, I'm new to json and jackson.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my json

```
[
    {
        "name": "aaa",
        "values" : {
            "value1" : 111,
            "value2" : 222,
            "value3" : 333
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "bbb",
        "values" : {
            "value1" : 444,
            "value2" : 555,
            "value3" : 666
        }
    }
]
```

and my classes:

```
public class Elements {
    
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("values")
    Values values;
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Values getValues() {
        return this.values;
    }

    public void setValues(Values values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

```
public class Values {
    @JsonProperty("value1")
    int value1;
    @JsonProperty("value2")
    int value2;
    @JsonProperty("value3")
    int value3;

    public int getValue1() {
        return this.value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(int value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public int getValue2() {
        return this.value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(int value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public int getValue3() {
        return this.value3;
    }

    public void setValue3(int value3) {
        this.value3 = value3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not do that conversion after deserialize, when you have already the objects populated? Are the values always 3?

Comment: try `objectMapper.readValue(json, Map.class)`

Comment: @Franjavi. Thanks this makes things a little bit easier but doesn't solve the problem on outer class. mapper.readValue(str, Elements.class) works only If I return a List Elements[].class.

Comment: Sorry @bbx402, I don't think I understand exactly what you need. What do you mean by outer class problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read it as a `List` of `Map` instances and collect it to a new `Map` after deserialisation process:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {});
Map<String, Object> desiredMap = listOfMaps.stream().collect(HashMap::new,
        (result, map) -> result.put(map.get("name").toString(), map.get("values")),
        (existing, replacement) -> { });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Michal.
Works. It looks like I need to get a list first and that I cannot get the HashMap directly.

Comment: @bbx402, sometimes much easier is to read in form it is defined in `JSON` payload and convert to desired format after that. If you would like to deserialise to `Map<String, Map>` directly you would have to create custom deserialiser.

Answer (score 0):

I've upvoted @Michal's answer as it is really cool and delivers what you asked for:

> I need a HashMap of type {name, HashMap<valuename, value>}

I don't understand why you have defined the `Elements` and `Values` classes if all you want is to store the data within a *HashMap of HashMaps*.

Out of curiosity, I tested Jackson with your classes and it works just fine:

```
// Deserialize as a list
List<Elements> listElements = objectMapper.readValue(JSON, new TypeReference<List<Elements>>(){});
// print elements
listElements.forEach(System.out::println);
```